# Is any fiberwise very ample line bundle relatively very ample?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X \to S$ be a proper morphism and $\mathcal{L}$ be a line bundle such that for any $s\in S$, $\mathcal{L}_s$ is a very ample line bundle. Is $\mathcal{L}$ an $f$-relatively very ample line bundle?

I know $\mathcal{L}$ is $f$-relatively ample by [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27972/relatively-ample-line-bundles). In fact, one can show more:
If $\mathcal{L}_s$ is ample, then there exists an open neighborhood $s\in U$ such that $\mathcal{L}|_{f^{-1}(U)}$ is relatively ample on $f:f^{-1}(U)\to U$.

If we further assume $\Gamma(f^{-1}(U), \mathcal{L})\otimes k(s)\to \Gamma(X_s, \mathcal{L}_s)$ is surjective for some open neighborhood $s\in U$, then we can show that there exist an open neighborhood $x\in W\subseteq U$ such that $\mathcal{L}|_{f^{-1}(W)}$ is relatively very ample on $f:f^{-1}(W)\to W$ : By the assumption, there exist an open neighborhood $s\in V\subseteq U$ and $p:f^{-1}(V)\to \mathbb{P}_{V}^n$ such that $p_s$ is a closed immersion and $p^\ast O(1)\simeq \mathcal{L}|_{f^{-1}(V)}$. Then by some standard arguments, (e.g. Proposition 12.93 of Algebraic Geometry by Gortz & Wedhorn) we can show that there exist an open set $s\in W\subseteq V$ such that $p|_{f^{-1}(W)}$ is a closed immersion. Then $\mathcal{L}|_{f^{-1}(W)}$ is relatively very ample.

Hence I think the key point is proving $\Gamma(f^{-1}(U), \mathcal{L})\otimes k(s)\to \Gamma(X_s, \mathcal{L}_s)$ is surjective for some $U$. If $H^1(X_s, \mathcal{L}_s)=0$, then this holds by base change theorems (Theorem 12.11 of Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry). However, I can prove neither this one nor the original question without this additional assumption.

Comment: @wnx, I think you and I are using a different definition of relatively very ampleness. I'm using the definition of stack project (https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01VL). With this definition, any line bundle is relatively very ample with respect to the identity map: Since relatively very ampleness is a target-local property, we may assume that $X$ is affine and $\mathcal{L}$ is trivial. Since there exists a closed immersion $\text{Spec} A=\mathbb{P}_A^0$, trivial line bundle is very ample on an affine scheme.

Comment: Do you allow non-reduced fibers? If so suppose that $C$ is hyperelliptic with involution $\sigma$ such that $C/<\sigma>\cong \mathbb P^1$ and $\sigma$ also acts on $\mathbb P^1$ via $z\to z^{-1}$. Let $S=C\times \mathbb P^1/<\sigma>$ where $\sigma$ acts diagonally  and so there is a map to $\mathbb P^1\times \mathbb P^1\cong C\times \mathbb P^1/(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^2$. The second projection induces a fibration $S\to \mathbb P^1\cong \mathbb P^1/<\sigma>$ with "double" fibers over $0$ and $\infty$ isomorphic to $\mathbb P ^1$.

Comment: Let $L$ be the pullback of $\mathcal O _{\mathbb P^1}(1)$ via the first projection $S\to \mathbb P^1\cong C/<\sigma>$. Then $L|_{S_0}\cong \mathcal O _{\mathbb P^1}(1)$ is very ample, but $L_{S_t}$ is not very ample for $t\ne 0,\infty$.

Comment: @Hacon.  The restriction of the invertible sheaf to the reduced scheme of that fiber is very ample.  As you note, the fiber is nonreduced.  The invertible sheaf on the nonreduced fiber is *not* very ample.